# FindControl within ContentPage and UpdatePanel vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Stumped on this one, have searched various answers none were able to resolve. Keep getting `ctl00 is not declared due to protection level`

Don't get the error if I drop the `ct100` MasterPage and start with the `ContentPlaceHolder` but then I get null reference?

Also looking to see if the UpdatePanel also plays a role in this?

Also wanted to know why `Handles TextBox4.TextChanged` needed to be removed if inside MasterPage?

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="resetPassword.aspx.vb" Inherits="resetPass" title="reset PW" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <h2>Password Recovery</h2>

    <div style="border-style: double; background-color: #E7E7E7; width: 375px;">
    <div class="grayBox" 
            style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; text-align: center;">
        CHANGE / RESET PASSWORD</div>
    <br />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <contenttemplate>
                &nbsp;&nbsp; User Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox4_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp; Password Question:
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="?" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="14" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label><br />
                <div id="results" runat="server"></div>
                <br />
                 &nbsp;&nbsp; Password Answer:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp; New Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Change Password" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <div style="font-size: large; text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" Text-Align="center"></asp:Label></div>
                <br />
            </contenttemplate>
            <Triggers>

            </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

VB:

```
    Protected Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
        Dim ctl00 As MasterPage = TryCast(FindControl("ctl00"), MasterPage)
        Dim MainContent As ContentPlaceHolder = TryCast(FindControl("MainContent"), ContentPlaceHolder)
        Dim TB4 As TextBox = TryCast(ctl00.MainContent.FindControl("TextBox4"), TextBox)
        Dim uName As String = TB4.Text
        Dim u As MembershipUser = myProvider.GetUser(uName, True)
        Dim L1 As Label = ctl00.MainContent.FindControl("Label1")
        Try
            If u Is Nothing Then
                L1.Text = "No user found"
            Else
                L1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                L1.Text = u.PasswordQuestion
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'xxx
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: It could be a bad idea to give a variable the same name as a control.

Comment: what variable is the same?

Comment: noted.. but not the issue

Comment: Which line does the error appear on?

Comment: `Dim TB4 As TextBox = TryCast(ctl00.MainContent.FindControl("TextBox4"), TextBox)`

Comment: Is there a TextBox4 on the master page as well as the resetPassword page? If not, then you could use `Dim TB4 As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)`.

Comment: For the other part, you use either `OnTextChanged="TextBox4_TextChanged"` or `Handles TextBox4.TextChanged` because they both do they same thing (`AutoEventWireup` may change things).

Comment: ok the direct cast seems to work for the textbox but now the label gets error? Can't direct cast it

Comment: You should be able to use it directly as `Label1`. (Also, you should be able to use `TextBox4` directly, but I am in the habit of casting the sender to the type of control that sent it, in case I want to re-use parts of code.) Um, is there a reason you're trying to access the controls via the master page instead of directly?

Comment: in the past I've always had to FindControl because I have login controls inside the MasterPage - initially received that error. Thanks - post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I still get `Label1 is not declaired. It may be inaccessible due to protection level`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing content-page controls from that page's code-behind, you don't need to go via the master page.

So, instead of

```
Dim L1 As Label = ctl00.MainContent.FindControl("Label1")
L1.Text = "No user found"
```

you can use

```
Label1.Text = "No user found"
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you happen to have another `Label1` somewhere else too? More descriptive control names could be useful.

Comment: There should be a "resetPassword.aspx.designer.vb" file. If you open that in a text editor, can you see a declaration for `PQ1`?

Comment: where would I find `resetPassword.aspx.designer.vb` Ive never seen that?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project? Sometimes things get out of step. I don't know how many times I've saved a change to a code-behind page, forgotten to rebuild, and wondered why my changes weren't showing.

Comment: I expect that "resetPassword.aspx.designer.vb" will be in the same directory as "resetPassword.aspx".

Comment: I'm in .NET 3.5 is that a later version... don't have designer files at all

Comment: rebuild and restart VS also not resolving intellisense error

Comment: Finally Resolved... not sure why but I re-created button events and text_changed events with new control ID's and that cleaned up all the intellisense error and everything work : thanks again for the support

Comment: @BarclayVision I was hoping you'd be able to fix it while I was on my way home :) Yes, I also find that re-creating controls is needed to persuade it to work sometimes.